# SQL Get the first occurance of the 15th for a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I need to write a function or SP that will return the first occurance of the 15th. For example, if I pass the date as May 8th, then it should return May 15th. If I pass May 30th, then it should return June 15th.

Comment: Did you gave it a shot? Do you have some code that you tried?

Comment: Will this function always be passed the current date, or can it be passed any date at any time?

Comment: +1 @YAU I agree, SO seems to be becoming a "do my job for me" resource rather than a place for assistance with tough problems. It's hard to know where to draw the line, but I do think this question could be easily solved by reading the MSSQL Date functions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) and Control Logic (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174290.aspx) documentation. I understand the OP might learn something from the answers provided below, but it would be frustrating if not.

Answer (score 5):

One way

```
   DECLARE @d DATETIME
    SELECT @d = '20110508'
    --SELECT @d = '20110530'


    SELECT  CASE WHEN DAY(@d)  > 15 
    THEN  dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, @d)+1, 0) + 14
    ELSE dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, @d)+0, 0)+ 14 end
```

Comment: If you change `getdate()` to `@d` I think you'd have it.  It works now only if you are using a day that becomes 5-15 (or whatever is the correct result for today.)

Comment: In your first example: `SELECT  CASE WHEN DAY(@d)  > 15 
THEN  dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate())+1, 0) + 14
ELSE dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate())+0, 0)+ 14 end` this is wrong.  Try it with '20110710' and you will get 5-15.  Obviously that is wrong.  Because those `getdate()` in your first example need to be `@d`.  There is no indication by OP that you've assumed they will always pass the current date.

Comment: Subtract 15 days from @d before doing the datediff, instead of the CASE WHEN THEN?

Answer (score 3):

How about;

```
create function udf_getNextDate(@base datetime, @day int) returns datetime as begin
    set @base = case when day(@base) > @day         
            then dateadd(month, 1, @base)
        else @base
    end
    return dateadd(day, -day(@base) + @day, @base)
end

select 
  dbo.udf_getNextDate('08 may 2011', 15),
  dbo.udf_getNextDate('30 may 2011', 15),
  dbo.udf_getNextDate('16 dec 2011', 15),
  dbo.udf_getNextDate('01 may 2011', 15)

2011-05-15 00:00:00.000 
2011-06-15 00:00:00.000 
2012-01-15 00:00:00.000 
2011-05-15 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way of doing it:

```
Declare @d datetime

Set @d = getdate()


Select  Case 
            When    DateDiff(Day, Day(@d), 15) < 0 then 
                    DateAdd(month, 1, DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, Day(@d), 15), @d))
            Else    DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, Day(@d), 15), @d) 
        End as [Next15th]
```

Answer (score 1):

this function may helps you

```
create function Get15th(@date datetime)
returns datetime 
as
begin
declare @resultdate datetime
declare @y int
declare @m int
declare @d int
set @y = datepart(year,@date)
set @m = datepart(month,@date)
set @d = datepart(day,@date)
if( @d<=15)
set @resultdate =cast((str(@y)+'-'+str(@m)+'-15') as datetime)
else
set @resultdate =cast((str(@y)+'-'+str(@m+1)+'-15') as datetime)
return  @resultdate 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, 15, Created), 0) AS CreatedDay
```

explained here http://improve.dk/archive/2006/12/13/sql-server-datetime-rounding-made-easy.aspx

using that link you can achive what you want

UPDATE: got it wrong ... see Dems answer

Comment: Can you plug in `20110508` I get back 2011-04-23 00:00:00.000

Comment: The DateDiff's need to diff the months, not the days.  You're code is rounding the Created down to the nearest day, and subtracting 15 days...

Comment: @mellamokb - sorry I was unable to test this but did provide a link for the user to try to work it out for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Rob's answer is close...

if you take the datediff in months, rather than days, and make your base the 15'th of a month, then add one extra month...

<s>`DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 14, Created) + 1, 14)`</s>

**EDIT**

Modified to use DATEDIFF MONTH how it works, not how I thought it should work ;)

`DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Created - 15) + 1, 14)`

Comment: Not quite: 5-1 -> 6-15, is not the next occurrance.  5-1 should return **5-15**.  You need an extra check like `@SQLMenace` to handle before the 15th vs. after the 15th.

Comment: My mistake, should test.  Offset the created date by -15 days, to avoid using the CASE WHEN THEN.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this:

```
declare
  @date       datetime ,
  @target_day int

set @date       = 'June 16, 2009'
set @target_day = 15

select date      = @date ,
       next_date = case when day(@date) <= @target_day
                     then dateadd(day,15-day(@date),@date)
                     else dateadd(day,15,dateadd(month,1,dateadd(day,-day(@date),@date)))
                   end
```

dealing with the last day of the month is a wee bit trickier, since month's have variable numbers of days, and SQL Server's date math is sometimes a wee bit baroque.